# Facing an issue with Improsys Java API for AOL

Tags: java, api, aol, contact-list

We have been using Improsys java api for importing contact list. It was working fine. From last month, We are facing issue with this API when we are trying to get the contact list from AOL and its returning empty contact list. It is working fine for other mails like gmail, hotmail and yahoo.

With the latest jars, even gmail is also not working

Comment: Did you get error message or exception? if you get please post the error message.

Comment: No. There is no error. When i am trying to get the contacts, it is returning an empty list even though there are contacts for corresponding email.